# Working out leftovers from grouping

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Mike has 2015 matches and decides to put them in a triangular pattern. He starts with three at the top,then five,then seven,and so on. In the end ,how many matches does he have left over.

When I first saw it, I thought I had to divide it by 3, but it may not be the cause. Can someone simply explain

Answer (score 1):

We have the arithmetic series of $3, 5, 7, ...$. The common difference is $2$ and the first term is $3$. We want to find out how far the sum of these numbers can go without going over $2015$. Once we've found that, we can subtract that answer from $2015$ to find the number of mathces left over.

We can use the [partial sum of an arithmetic series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html) to find the the sum of the first $n$ terms is $\frac n 2[2*3+2(n-1)]=3n+n(n-1)$. Thus, we need to find the maximum $n$ that satisfies the following inequality:
$$3n+n(n-1) < 2015$$
Simplify the left side of the inequality:
$$n^2+2n < 2015$$
Subtract everything by $2015$:
$$n^2+2n-2015 < 0$$
Use the quadratic formula to find that the two zeroes of this polynomial are $-1-12\sqrt{14}$ and $12\sqrt{14}-1$. The polynomial is less than $0$ between the zeroes so we need to find the greatest integer $n$ such that $-1-12\sqrt{14}<n<12\sqrt{14}-1$. By using a calculator, we can find that this inequality is approximately $-45.9<n<43.9$, meaning the greatest integer satisfying it is clearly $43$.

Thus, we need to find the partial sum of the first $43$ terms of this sequence. By plugging $n=43$ into our formula, we find that $3*43+43(43-1)=1935$ matches were used to make the pattern. By subtracting this from $2015$, we find that there were $80$ matches left over, which is our answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I am having trouble understanding the second paragraph. Also, I have the answer(which I don't  understand), but it is 37.

Comment: Hm...That's odd. I do not know how the answer could be $37$. If you want to know the number of sticks he put down in each row, it is 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87. He then needs to stop because he only has $80$ sticks left at this point, so he can not make another row of $89$ sticks.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the second paragraph. Can you please explain better? Also, I have the answer(which I don't understand), but it is 37,so please re-check.

Comment: Sorry for the second comment. I gave it to you by accident

Comment: For the second paragraph, basically, what I did was I found a formula to find the number of sticks he put down after $n$ rows. I did this by using something called a partial sum formula from the link I linked to that sums up the first $n$ terms of the arithmetic sequence. After finding that formula, because we know that Mike only has $2015$ sticks, the number of sticks he put down must be $< 2015$, which is how I got the inequality.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to leave now, but if you have any more questions, I will answer them later.

Comment: I think you should have put a line on the bottom of the pyramid so it is not open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34945/discussion-between-noble-mushtak-and-ezekiel).